# Swift 3 load image from local directory

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm new to iOS dev and cannot figure out how to load an image in an imageView from a local directory.
I use imagePickerController to pick an image, get its info, then use this information to display the image in the imageView.

Here is the code to pick the image and its info dictionary:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image             = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
        let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
        let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)!

        imagesList.append(localPath)

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Then, and here is where I'm looking for some help, I want to use either localPath or imageUrl to load the image in another imageView but cannot figure out how.
I tried

```
func changeImage(_ sender: Any) {
        if imagesList.count > 0 {
            let imageUrlPath = imagesList[indexList]
            let urlString: String = imageUrlPath.absoluteString

            imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: urlString)

            indexList = (indexList + 1) % imagesList.count
        }
    }
```

But I cannot have something working.
Any idea how I can achieve that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to use `imageUrlPath.path` instead of `imageUrlPath.absoluteString`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't have any error but the image is not displayed in the imageView. If I print urlString, it contains only "/asset.JPG" and I don't think that's enough.

What contentsOfFile is supposed to contain: the whole path (file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BF7D44E4-26DD-43EE-5543-D7AB7654F8DC/data/Containers/Data/Application/C9561694-34E9-46AD-83AA-38F067557F86/Documents/asset.JPG)? Or something like "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=9A443DCB-EC44-42B8-8773-B597CF782EDD&ext=JPG"

Comment: Print the path and check that image is exist or not

Comment: I don't know if I'm using the right variable (`urlString`) to check the existence of the file or not but it seems that the file does not exist.
Here is the code 
`if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: urlString) {
                print("File exists")
            } else {
                print("File not found")
            }
`

Comment: Do you want to save and re-use a reference to the file on disk? Or do you just need to get the image and assign it to a UIImage var or .image property of a UIImageView?

Comment: Both. I'd want to use it immediately to display the image and save it for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to save a reference to PHAsset objects, not URL strings.

Start with defining your Array as:

```
var imagesList = [PHAsset]()
```

Then, in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    dismiss(animated: true)

    // get the selected image as a UIImage object
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    imageView.image = image

    // save a PHAsset reference in imagesList array for later use
    if let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL{

        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageUrl], options: nil)

        if let p = assets.firstObject {

            imagesList.append(p)

        }

    }

}
```

Next, add a couple "convenience" functions:

```
func getAssetFullsize(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var img = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    let w = asset.pixelWidth
    let h = asset.pixelHeight
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: w, height: h), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        img = result!
    })
    return img
}

func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    let w = 100
    let h = 100
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: w, height: h), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        thumbnail = result!
    })
    return thumbnail
}
```

and finally, when you want to get the actual image:

```
func changeImage(_ sender: Any) {
    if imagesList.count > 0 {

        // get the full-size image from PHAsset
        imageView.image = getAssetFullsize(asset: imagesList[indexList])

        // or, just get a thumbnail-sized image
        //imageView.image = getAssetThumbnail(asset: imagesList[indexList])

        indexList = (indexList + 1) % imagesList.count

    }
}
```

Naturally, you'll want to add appropriate error-checking, your own sizing, naming, tracking, etc... but I think this is the direction you want to head.

Comment: Thanks a lot DonMag, I'll answer longer later when I'll test that.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.